# Python: For loop in a function string variable

Tags: python-3.x, regex, function, for-loop, os.walk

I am python beginner trying to build my first project on my own after many months of theory, reading python books, and online udemy courses.

I have a function with a for loop that uses os.walk to find all video(tv show) files. I am later

```
VIDEO_EXTENSIONS = ('.wmv', '.avi', '.mkv', '.mp4', '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.mov')
  
def vid_file():
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk(root_path):
        for video_filename in files:
            if video_filename.endswith(VIDEO_EXTENSIONS):
                print(video_filename)
```

If I call this function, I get all video files in root_path but its not of type string, its .
Output of vid_file() is something like:

```
tv.show.s01e01.episode.name.mkv
tv.show.s01e02.episode.name.mkv
```

When trying to use regular expressions to split out the season info of a file it does not work because it is not a string.

```
print(re.split(season, vid_file()))
```

Error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./re_org.py", line 60, in <module>
    print(re.split(season, vid_file()))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 231, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

OK no problem. In function vid_file(), I thought I will just change 'print()' to 'return video_filename'.
This will work but for only 1 file and not all files found in the for loop from the vid_file() function.

```
season = re.compile(r'S\d+')    
print(re.split(season, vid_file()))
```

output:

```
['tv.show.', 'e06.episode.name.mkv']
```

I feel like I'm missing something about how for loops and functions work but don't know what. Any help with the best way to move forward and explanation on how it works is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your requirements correctly, would you please try:

```
import os

VIDEO_EXTENSIONS = ('.wmv', '.avi', '.mkv', '.mp4', '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.mov')

def vid_file(dir):
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk(dir):
        for video_filename in files:
            if video_filename.endswith(VIDEO_EXTENSIONS):
                yield os.path.join(root, video_filename)

root_path = "."           # or wherever you want
l = list(vid_file(root_path))
print(l)
```

The function `vid_file()` returns a generator and the list `l` contains the list of video files.

Comment: python gives error cannot assign to literal `1`. I change this to something like `vid_list` and I now have a list to work with. From here I can not pass this to `print(re.split(season, vid_list))` I get error 
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./re_org.py", line 63, in <module>
    print(re.split(season, vid_list))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/re.py", line 231, in split
    return _compile(pattern, flags).split(string, maxsplit)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` 
I will try combined with @8349697 solution. Thank you!

Comment: I figured it out. in `print(re.split(season, vid_list))` I needed to put the variable into `str(vid_list)`
Your solution is very simple with minimal lines of code. Very elegant.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Please note the lvalue is not `1` (one) but `l` (el).

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like I'm missing something about how for loops and functions
> work but don't know what.

You need to **return** [an iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) with the results of the function execution (list, generator, etc.)

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions):

> In fact, even functions without a return statement do return a value,
> albeit a rather boring one. This value is called None (it’s a built-in
> name). Writing the value None is normally suppressed by the
> interpreter if it would be the only value written.

```py
def a():
    pass

def b():
    return

def c():
    return ['file1', 'file2']

def d():
    for f in ['file1', 'file2']:
        print(f, end=" ")

print(a()) # None
print(b()) # None
print(c()) # ['file1', 'file2']
print(d()) # file1 file2 None
```

---

You are using a split function that expects a string and gets None instead.

```
print(re.split(season, vid_file()))
```

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split):

> `re.split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)`
>
> Split string by the occurrences of pattern.

```
print(re.split(pattern=season, string=vid_file()))
```

---

> In function vid_file() i'll just change 'print()' to 'return
> video_filename'.

If you did it like this...

```py
if video_filename.endswith(VIDEO_EXTENSIONS):
    return video_filename # return one file
```

this means that you exit the loop as soon as you find the first matching file.

---

Code example:

```py
import os
import re
from typing import Tuple, List # optional


VIDEO_EXTENSIONS = ('.wmv', '.avi', '.mkv', '.mp4', '.mpg', '.mpeg', '.mov')
season = re.compile(r's\d+')

def vid_file():
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk('.'):
        for video_filename in files:
            if video_filename.endswith(VIDEO_EXTENSIONS):
                print(video_filename)

 
result = vid_file() # prints filenames, return None
print(result) # None
print(type(result)) # <class 'NoneType'>

# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object:
# print(re.split(season, result))


def vid_file(extensions: Tuple[str]) -> List[str]:
    result = []
    for root, subdir, files in os.walk('.'):
        for video_filename in files:
            if video_filename.endswith(extensions):
                # add filename to list
                result.append(video_filename)

    return result


result = vid_file(VIDEO_EXTENSIONS) # return list with filenames
print(result)
print(type(result)) # <class 'list'>
print(type(result[0])) # <class 'str'>

# suppose we found matching files
files = [
    'tv.show.s01e01.episode.name.mkv',
    'tv.show.s01e02.episode.name.mkv'
    ]

for f in files: # f is a string
    print(re.split(season, f))

# ['tv.show.', 'e01.episode.name.mkv']
# ['tv.show.', 'e02.episode.name.mkv']
```